# I don't want to give you excuses

Tags: phrases

I haven't been able to work on my thesis due to my ongoing masters and work obligations. I'd like to get in touch with my advisor regarding that, and I don't want to sound like I'm making up excuses because I really can't find the time to work on the thesis.

Would the phrase "I don't want to give you excuses, but" < situation description > be ok?

Comment: We'd normally say "I don't want to *make* excuses, but...". That said, your phrasing is ok too.

Comment: With @DanBron's note in mind, the sentence is fine, but this kind of wording is sometimes seen as a cliche, introducing actual excuses. The same goes for "I don't want to criticize, _but_ (insert criticism)" or "I don't want to tell you what to do, _but_ (insert detailed orders)".

Comment: "Don’t **make excuses.** Don’t rationalise your failure by placing the blame on someone or something else. ... Those who **give excuses** get excluded." http://leadership.ng/religion/405127/success-methods-planning-execution-redoing-3

Comment: "The Manchester City manager did not want to **make excuses** for his team's performance but remains confident they will get out of the group. ... while the manager refused to **give excuses** for the second-half performance, he insisted he is “sure” that the team will make the last-16." http://www.manchestereveningnews.co.uk/sport/football/football-news/defiant-pellegrini-insists-man-city-7975488

Comment: "We can't **give excuses** for our skill. We know exactly what situation we have to face and prepare for that in training. We can't **make excuses** about wet balls and things like that." http://www.icc-cricket.com/news/2014/features-and-specials/79745/knockout-time-for-sri-lanka-new-zealand

Comment: If you are going to give an excuse, why not say 'I'd like to give you an excuse, so ...'?

Comment: Think about going to your advisor and starting off with "I am overwhelmed".  It sounds as though you are, from your comment about 40 to 50 hours of work per week, plus the course, plus the thesis.  As for the other obligations that "pop up", make a list of those and decide if they really are obligations -- maybe some of them are not.   Also, try to come up with a plan before you see your advisor.  And your problem isn't about English, it is about your academic schedule.  Look at http://academia.stackexchange.com/ and think about deleting your question here and rephrasing it for Academia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about: *I am not making up excuses but*...

Or

" *I know how much you hate your students making up excuses but I really just was...*"

Comment: We can use "comments" to post our opinions.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a genuine problem with respect to the completion of your  thesis it would sound far better to start with an apology and then explain your problem ,maybe it is not necessary to talk about making up excuses
...

Comment: The thing is that the whole course is very strenuous on students. It's a part time course which takes up around 20 hours a week plus I work which is additional 40-50 hours a week. Of course, there are other obligations that simply pop out every so often. On top of that we have to do a thesis, which I simply can't do. So, I don't want to make excuses, but the reality is such that the strain is big and I just can't make it as it currently stands..

Answer (score 2):

You could say

"I don't like to give excuses, but I have been really running from pillar to post over the past one week"
You can add that some of the obligations took more of your time than you anticipated and hence you ended up with little to no time to dedicate to the thesis. And you really wanted to make a good job of the thesis, so you need more time.

Good luck :)

Comment: If you include the link to the [idiom](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/from+pillar+to+post), and explain the meaning, it would strengthen an already good answer. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/from_pillar_to_post